# Portforwarding SSH to my server but does not work when server is on VPN, asymmetric routing?

Tags: linux, vpn, port-forwarding, iptables

I want to open SSH from internet to my server so I have a port-forwarding rule on my router to forward port 22 external to my server:22, works fine as long as my server is Not connected to VPN. I think asymmetric routing is occurring where the SSH connection comes in to my local IP address and the response goes out on the VPN, makes sense?

Is it possible to change gateway with iptables, like "if src port is 22 then use gateway 192.168.10.1 on interface br0 instead of default gateway"?

Server IP: 192.168.10.10

Gateway  : 192.168.10.1

Interface: br0

ip a:

```bsh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:a9:19:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp11s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:a9:16:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 62:c4:b2:98:46:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.10/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::60c4:b2ff:fe98:46f6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:28:c4:e5:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-aad69972cc43: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:b8:6b:d5:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.0.1/16 brd 172.30.255.255 scope global br-aad69972cc43
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.10.0.5/16 brd 10.10.255.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdda:d0d0:cafe:1196::1003/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7ff9:6b31:c261:212b/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

iptables configuration:

```bsh
GATEWAY="192.168.10.1"
IP="192.168.10.10"

# Remove current rules
iptables --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables -t nat --flush
iptables -t nat --delete-chain

# Drop by default
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P INPUT  DROP

# Allow loopack
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -i lo
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o lo

# Allow DNS-client request to 1.1.1.1
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -s $IP --sport 1024:65535 -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 1.1.1.1 --sport 53 -d $IP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s $IP --sport 1024:65535 -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.1.1.1 --sport 53 -d $IP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS-client request to 8.8.8.8
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -s $IP --sport 1024:65535 -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 8.8.8.8 --sport 53 -d $IP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s $IP --sport 1024:65535 -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 8.8.8.8 --sport 53 -d $IP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allows internal traffic from on interface br0
iptables -A INPUT --src 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT -i br0
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT -o br0

# Allow ssh connections from everywhere, limit connection to 1/minute
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m limit --limit 1/minute -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o br0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow VPN (mullvad CZ) on interface br0 @ port 1196
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -d 185.156.174.170 -o br0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1196
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -s 185.156.174.170 -i br0 -p udp -m udp --sport 1196
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -d 185.156.174.146 -o br0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1196
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -s 185.156.174.146 -i br0 -p udp -m udp --sport 1196

# Allow everything on tun0
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -i tun0
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o tun0
```